# Beacon trigger actionPayload available actions?

Tags: ibeacon, ibm-mobilefirst

I just started learning beacons in MFP and have question concerning actionPayload for a trigger. Knowledge Center gives JSON example with

"actionPayload" : {"alert" : "Avail lowest interest rate of just 7.5% on       home loans!"}

I'm trying to realize:

- What are the actions available except of alert?
- How could I define callback function for the trigger?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use as-is the following function in `iOSNativeiBeacons/iOSNativeiBeaconsLibrary/WLBeaconsLocationManager.m`, then beacon-trigger's `actionPayload` can either be a local alert or a call to an adapter procedure. The details of adapter call are given next.

```
-(void) fireTriggerAction:(WLBeaconTrigger *)beaconTrigger forWLBeacon:(WLBeacon *)wlBeacon
{
    NSString *branchName = [wlBeacon.customData objectForKey:@"branchName"];
    NSString *alertMessage = [beaconTrigger.actionPayload objectForKey:@"alert"];
    if(alertMessage != nil) {
        alertMessage = [alertMessage stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"$branchName" withString:branchName];
        NSString *alertTitle = [WLBeaconTrigger beaconTriggerTypeToString:beaconTrigger.triggerType];
        [self sendLocalNotification:alertTitle withMessage:alertMessage];
    } else {
        NSString *adapterName = [beaconTrigger.actionPayload objectForKey:@"adapterName"];
        NSString *procedureName = [beaconTrigger.actionPayload objectForKey:@"procedureName"];
        NSString *userName = [self getUserName];
        [self invokeAdapterProcedure:adapterName withProcedure:procedureName forUser:userName forBranch:branchName];
    };
}
```

In a beacon-enabled banking app scenario, suppose we want to inform the bank branch manager when a high value customer enters the loan section of the branch, then following trigger can be registered and associated with the loan-section beacons.

beacon-trigger:

```
{
    "triggerName" : "EnterLoanSection",
    "triggerType" : "Enter",
    "proximityState" : "Near",
    "actionPayload" : {
        "adapterName" : "BeaconsAdapter",
        "procedureName" : "sendNotificationToBranchManager"
    }
}
```

The `actionPayload` in the trigger above specifies that the procedure `sendNotificationToBranchManager` of adapter `BeaconsAdapter` should be called upon entering the near proximity of associated beacons. That procedure will be defined in the adapter-files as below:

BeaconsAdapter.xml:

```
<procedure name="sendNotificationToBranchManager" />
```

BeaconsAdapter-impl.js:

```
function sendNotificationToBranchManager(userName, branchName) {
    var notification = {};
    notification.message = {};
    notification.message.alert = "HNI customer, " + userName + ", is in loan-section of " + branchName + " branch.";
    notification.settings = {};

    WL.Server.sendMessage("ManagerApp", notification);

    return {
        result : "Notification sent"
    };
}
```

Regarding "How could I define callback function for the trigger?", you could modify `-(void) fireTriggerAction:(WLBeaconTrigger *)beaconTrigger forWLBeacon:(WLBeacon *)wlBeacon` in `iOSNativeiBeacons/iOSNativeiBeaconsLibrary/WLBeaconsLocationManager.m`